Do you know who was the first person to land/landing on the moon?

Do you know who was the first person to land on the moon?

Is it also right to use present participle "landing " to modify "the first person"?
Is there any difference to use infinitive and present participle to modify the subject?

In general, yes.  In this particular case "no".  . .  You should fix how you form questions:  "Is it right"  (not "does it right")  and "Does it make any difference" or "Is there any difference". (not "does it any difference")

Two people were the first to land on the moon; one of them was first to step on the surface.

How exactly are you planning to modify "the first person"? It would be much more useful if you give us a sentence to judge. ("Who was the first person landing?" "Who was the first landing person?" or what?)

Do you know who was the first person to land on the moon? does not actually ask Who was the first person to land on the moon?

Do you know who the first person to walk on the moon was? This is the correct way to formulate indirect questions. We talk about "the first man to walk on the moon."

Grammatically, the correct phrase is "who was the first person to land on the moon."
Let's consider the alternative you suggest, "who was the first person landing on the moon."
This brings to mind the present continuous tense (also formed with -ing.)  I picture "He is landing", "he is in the process of landing", a continuous ongoing action, occurring through a period of time.
However, when we speak about past events, they are often imagined as fixed and immobile in time. They are complete. The infinite is used: "The first to land".
In Indian English they have a tendency to prefer the present participle form. Perhaps in that dialect it is "correct", but not in most other regions.

Edit: "There were actually two men who landed at the same time. The Apollo Lunar Modules had crews of two. The first men to land on the Moon were Neil Armstrong and Edwin “Buzz” Aldrin. Neil was the first one to exit the spacecraft and became the first person in all human history to walk on the Moon." - Odysseus Rex

There was no single person who was first to land on the moon, or doesn't that matter?

Yes, this is a test about grammar to examine the use of non-predicate verbs.
